# Break line using regex

Tags: regex

I have multiple xml files that look like this: `<TEST><TEST><TEST><TEST><TEST><TEST><TEST><TEST><TEST><TEST>`
I would like to break into a new like for every '<' and get rid of every '>'.
I want to do this via regex since what I'm working on is for *nix.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use `regex` for such a simple search & replace.

Comment: Although you might be right, this comment is not helping me understand anything. I'm no expert in regex and I'm trying to do something to both learn and solve a problem I have. Please refrain on posting any comments if your not helping at all.

Comment: Well, actually @axi was right here, as they clearly pointed you to the right direction: search and replace...

Comment: Let me rephrase: your question asks how to replace `<` with `\n<` and `>` with an empty string. There is no `regex` involved here. It's a simple task for `sed`, f.e.

Comment: Want a helping comment? Edit the question, select the XML code and push the `{}` button from the editor's toolbar. It will insert 4 spaces in front of each selected line, the Markdown way to format it as code.

Comment: I never thought of using sed since I do not know how to use that. Please enlighten me.

Comment: Again, I would like to use regex for this. If it can be done using sed, please share an example.

Comment: *"I would like to use regex for this"* -- [now you have two problems](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for `regex` to do such a simple search & replace. You want to replace `<` with `\n<` and `>` with an empty string.

Assuming your content is in file `input.txt`, this simple `sed` command line can do the job:

```
sed 's/</\n</g;s/>//g' input.txt
```

### How it works

There are two `sed` commands separated by `;`:

```
s/</\n</g
s/>//g
```

Both commands are `s` (search and replace). The `s` command requires the search `regex` (no regex here), the replacement string and some optional flag, separated by `/`.

The first `s` searches for `<` and replaces it with `\n<`. `\n` is the usual notation for a newline character in `regex` and many Unix tools (even when no `regex` is involved).

The second `s` searches for `>` and replaces it with nothing.

Both `s` commands use the `g` (**global**) flag that tells them to do all the replacements they can do on each line. `sed` runs each command for every line of the input and by default, `s` stops after the first replacement (on a line).